# Firefox WebDriver: error in command_processor.js?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, autoit

From began:

I connect AutoIT with Selenium
[tutorial](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/)
then I used:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\AutoIt\AutoItTest.exe");
driver.get("http://www.example.com");
```

And naw I’m have a big problem:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: [JavaScript Error: "a is null" {file:...anonymous654436572778016798webdriverprofile/extensions/
fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js" line: 8732}]'
[JavaScript Error: "a is null" {file: ".../AppData/Local/Temp/
anonymous654436572778016798webdriverprofile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com
/components/command_processor.js" line: 8732}]' 
when calling method: [nsICommandProcessor::execute]
```

Comment: Having the same problem, any solutions?